# Symfony2 storing editable parameters

Tags: symfony, configuration

I need to create something like "configuration page". Users will be able to edit their settings using configuration-form. Configuration should be easily get from code. Configuration should supports different types of settings(scalars, arrays)

The question is: how to storing this settings?
For now i have two ideas:

- using ConfigTreeBuilder and storing in config file
- using something like EAV and storing in database

thanks

Comment: `ConfigTreeBuilder` is used only for semantic configuration done by bundle user, not application (I mean web application) user.

Comment: This may be of some use - http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusSettingsBundle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Both is good.

Here a example with the parameters_user.yml

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Dumper;

public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    $dir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/config/';
    $filename = 'parameters_user.yml';
    $path = $dir . $filename;

    $yaml = new Parser();
    try {
        $values = $yaml->parse(file_get_contents($path));
    } catch (ParseException $e) {
        printf("Unable to parse the YAML string: %s", $e->getMessage());
    }

    $config = new Config();
    $config->setConfig($values['parameters']);

    $form = $this->createForm(new ConfigType, $config);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $this->processForm($form, $path);

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}

private function processForm($form, $path) {
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $config = $form->getData();

        $values['parameters'] = $config->toArray();

        $dumper = new Dumper();
        $yaml = $dumper->dump($values, 2);
        file_put_contents($path, $yaml);
    }
}
```